# Prove that as $u \to 0$, $\frac{2-\varphi(u)-\varphi(-u)}{u^2} \to E(X^2)$

Tags: probability-theory

X, a real random variable, $\varphi(u)$ is defined as a characteristic function for X, $\varphi$: $R\to C$, $\varphi(u)=E(e^{iuX})$ for all u$\in R$.

Our professor gave us a hint that 1-cos $\theta$ =2$sin^2(\theta/2)$.

I really didn't get this problem or this hint. It seems like there is some gap in my knowledge, because I couldn't see the connection of this characteristic function containing complex number and the trigometric function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the identity $\cos \theta = \frac{1}{2}(e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta})$, we have

\begin{align*}
\frac{2-\varphi(u)-\varphi(-u)}{u^2}
&= \Bbb{E}\bigg[ \frac{2}{u^2}\left(1 - \frac{e^{iuX} + e^{-iuX}}{2} \right) \bigg]\\
&= \Bbb{E}\bigg[ \frac{2(1 - \cos (uX))}{u^2} \bigg]\\
&= \Bbb{E}\bigg[ \frac{4\sin^2(uX/2)}{u^2} \bigg].
\end{align*}

In order to utilize this computation, we observe from the inequality $\left| \sin\theta \right| \leq \left|\theta\right|$ that

$$ 0 \leq \frac{4\sin^2(uX/2)}{u^2} \leq X^2
\quad \text{and} \quad
\lim_{u\to0} \frac{4\sin^2(uX/2)}{u^2} = X^2. $$

Thus if $\Bbb{E}[X^2] < \infty$, then by the dominated convergence theorem we have

$$ \lim_{u \to 0} \frac{2-\varphi(u)-\varphi(-u)}{u^2}
= \Bbb{E}\bigg[ \lim_{u \to 0} \frac{4\sin^2(uX/2)}{u^2} \bigg]
= \Bbb{E}[X^2] $$

as desired. When $\Bbb{E}[X^2] = \infty$, then by the Fatou's lemma

$$ \liminf_{u \to 0} \frac{2-\varphi(u)-\varphi(-u)}{u^2}
\geq \Bbb{E}\bigg[ \liminf_{u \to 0}  \frac{4\sin^2(uX/2)}{u^2} \bigg]
= \Bbb{E}[X^2]
= \infty. $$

Therefore the conclusion holds unconditionally.

Comment: Thank you very much! @Sangchul Lee, now I see where is my gap, I don't know this equation that connecting the exponential containing the complex number and cos.

Comment: There is a little problem in your proof. There is no assumption that $E[X^2] \lt \infty$ so we cannot use dominated convergence theorem right? However, based on the work, we can just use monotone convergence theorem, right?

Comment: @Userkkr, I guess that you missed the last part of my proof. I divided the proof into two cases, $\Bbb{E}[X^2] < \infty$ and $\Bbb{E}[X^2] = \infty$, then proved each case separately. And I doubt that $4\sin^2(uX/2)/u^2$ increases as $u \to 0$. (It eventually increase for each fixed $\omega$, but the point at which this becomes increasing may vary for $\omega$.)

Comment: Yes! Thank you! But is there any method that can be used without using dominated convergence theorem discussing through cases?